# Why does the SimpleHTTPServer not serve wav files when serving a node.js app?

Tags: python, simplehttpserver

When I do a

```
http://localhost:8090/
```

Most of the files in the root directory are displayed: e.g. `.js` and `.py` . But all of the `.wav` files are omitted.  When trying to access it directly:

```
localhost:8090/mywav.wav
```

a `404` is returned.   Is there some configuration causing this?

Comment: Does it serve other binary files like .jpg?

Comment: @Pie'Oh'Pah see my answer: it seems that `node.js` is whitelisting the files. Need to re-do `npm init`.

Comment: Great. What does that have to do with Python server?

Comment: Indirectly plenty : this is a common usage pattern to serve node.js   I'll add `node.js` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this has to do with  `node.js`.  On a hunch I re-ran

```
 npm init
```

Now the wav files - which I had added recently after the initial `npm init` do show up.  So .. does that mean that `node` is *whitelisting* files - presumably for security purposes?   I still do wonder then if there were a way to disable that given this is a `localhost` server accessed by me myself and I.